# What type OData Edm.GeographyPoint refers to in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, odata, geography, sqlgeography

Which column type refers to OData Edm.GeographyPoint in a SQL Server database? There is no explanation how can we use this type while integrating with SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

DbGeography is map to a lot of types, include Edm.GeographyPoint.